# How to get the difference between current value and the previous value in the influx db

Tags: linux, bash, grafana, collectd

I am using **collectd** to push my system metric, **influxdb** as by database and **grafana** for visualization.

I need to monitor the network metric

**Tx-is total number of packets transmitted.
RX packets are the total number of packets received.**

I need to push my metric for every minute from collectd and I need to see how many packets are received or transmitted per minute in grafana..**.How can I query grafana like I will get the metric for every minute and I need to see the graph in grafana...**

Please help me

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a query like this can handle that:

```
SELECT count({a fieldname is reapeated in every record}) 
FROM {measurementsName} 
WHERE time >= now() - 1m;
```

You can insert this query on a singlestat panel in grafana.

[image]

Comment: you are right there is one problem. I attach a picture above. test it.

Comment: thanks for the reply....I used the query as per your image ..am getting error ...am attaching the image above...pls help me

Comment: your query is "now" but the query must be "now()"

Comment: sorry for the late reply...I am attaching the image above...am getting error...can u help me pls

Comment: changed you "now" to "now()"?